# how to provision aws resource using chef cookbook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

## Chef server for AWS INFRASTRUCTURE provisioning

I'm using aws cook book in chef and I'm adding vpc creation:

```
my_vpc = aws_vpc 'my_vpc' do
  cidr_block '10.0.0.0/24'
  main_routes '0.0.0.0/0' => :internet_gateway
  internet_gateway true`enter code here`
end

my_sg = aws_security_group 'my_sg' do
  vpc lazy { my_vpc.aws_object.id }
  inbound_rules '0.0.0.0/0' => [ 22, 80 ]
end

my_subnet = aws_subnet 'my_subnet' do
  vpc lazy { my_vpc.aws_object.id }
  cidr_block '10.0.0.0/24'
  availability_zone 'eu-west-1a'
  map_public_ip_on_launch true
end

machine 'my_machine' do
  machine_options(
    lazy do
      {
        bootstrap_options: {
          subnet_id: my_subnet.aws_object.id,
          security_group_ids: [my_sg.aws_object.id]
        }
      }
    end
  )
end
```

I'm experiencing "undefined method" error

### NoMethodError

```
undefined method `aws_vpc' for cookbook: chef-aws, recipe: default :Chef::Recipe
```

Comment: [root@chef cookbooks]# chef --version
Chef Workstation version: 0.12.20
Chef Infra Client version: 15.5.16
Chef InSpec version: 4.18.39
Chef CLI version: 2.0.0
Test Kitchen version: 2.3.4
Cookstyle version: 5.13.7
[root@chef cookbooks]#

Comment: this cookbook    knife supermarket download aws

Comment: Add additional information by editing your original post.

Comment: I am using the resources:

Comment: chefignore  starter  test
[root@chef cookbooks]# gem --version
3.0.6
[root@chef cookbooks]# ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
[root@chef cookbooks]# chef --version
ChefDK version: 4.5.0
Chef Infra Client version: 15.5.16
Chef InSpec version: 4.18.39
Test Kitchen version: 2.3.4
Foodcritic version: 16.2.0
Cookstyle version: 5.13.7

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution for chef aws provisioning.

1. Using aws cookbook in supermarket.
2. To create a cloudformation stack in aws
3. Using cloud formation template
   then this creating an own infra in aws.